# How to decode mongo wire traffic

Tags: mongodb, networking, wireshark

I want to use wireshark to check mongo wire protocol, so I tried to disable SSL, but it does not work.
I tried to disable in server config, in the mongo.conf

```
net:
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1, ::1 
  ipv6: true
  ssl:
    mode: disabled
security:
  authorization: disabled
```

And also tried on the mongo parmaters:

```
mongosh localhost?ssl=false
```

They are not work. I am using mongodb 5.0.8, I also tested on 5.0.7, on both linux & mac platform.

Even I used sample data from https://wiki.wireshark.org/Mongo, I only see the TCP & SSL data, mongo wire data is encrypted.

Comment: I can't explain `wireshark` behavior, but after I disabled its TLS and TLS over TCP protocols, and then selected "Decode as..." "MONGO", the dissection appeared to work.  Even after re-enabling wireshark's TLS/etc., the "MONGO" dissection continued to work.

Comment: Decode as mongo does not work in my wireshark(Both mac & linux). I even can see the correct data in SSL payload in char format.

Comment: Did you restart the MongoDB service?

Comment: Yes, I restart mongod everytime I update conf

Comment: Would you post (hex/ASCII) the "SSL" data you see in `wireshark`? I suspect you are experiencing a purely `wireshark` issue, not any `MongoDB` issue. The incorrect SSL dissector is being used instead of the correct MONGO dissector.

Answer (score 1):

I think I fixed this issue.
I need to manually decode packets by "decode as". I selected SSL packet at the first time, but it can not decode. Today I selected TCP packet and select "decode as..." and select MONGO. Now I can see mongo wire protocol now.

Thanks for rickhg12hs.